# (node:19652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'password' before initialization

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't know how should i resolve this error..
also , i got a warning which says: Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

```
const express =require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const User = require('./model/user.js')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/login-app-db',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
const app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/register', async(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const {username, password: plainTextPassword}= req.body;
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
   
    try {
        const response = await User.create({
            username,
            password
        })
        console.log('User created successfully:', response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.json({ status: 'Error'});
    }
 console.log(await bcrypt.hash(password, 10));

    res.json({status: 'ok'})
})

app.listen(9999, () => {
    console.log('Server Running at \'localhost:9999\'');
})
```

my package dependencies:

```
 "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
```

any hints ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you parse data from your front.
And edit your code and make it simple and less verbose.

Tips : At last you use these :

1. body-parser
2. CORS

This should work.

```
app.post('/api/register', async(req, res)=>{
    
    
    req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
    const response = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await response.save()
        return res.status(200).json({status : 'ok'})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.json({ status: 'Error'});
    }
})
```

Comment: Let me know if you have problem

Comment: it throws  some gibberish

Comment: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: login-app-db.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: "gbseaw3" }
    at Function.create (C:\Users\nshnk\Myfiles\codestuffs\Git_repos\Auth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12)        
    at toError (C:\Users\nshnk\Myfiles\codestuffs\Git_repos\Auth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123:22)
@MManana

Comment: Can you share your Schema here? you may indexed a fields but you don't provide values for it so it will be null refer to mongodb docs - [Mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field)

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true}
},
{collection: 'users'}
)


const model = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema);

module.exports = model;

Comment: Your code should work - just make sure your req.body.username is provided else you get ```null``` and raise error because username is unique and should be fill.

Comment: Thanks.....actually i pressed submit button twice which made MongoError

Comment: Also, instead of "password" in line:
``` const password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);````
using "plainTextPassword" resolved my issue